Movie about a teacher (more than likely white) in an inner city black school.
So there's this teacher in an inner city predominantly black school. The usual, bad neighbourhood, bad grades and protagonists teacher and student. So the student is a really quiet black boy. But he's brilliant at drawing and sketching (mostly comic book sketches). At one stage he draws on the desk and the teacher catches him but instead of getting mad at him, he photocopies the desk because the drawings are so good. I think in another scene the teacher shows up at the students house because he's been absent for a while and he sees what bad conditions the boy has been living in. The teacher finds/sees/is shown more of the kids drawings and one is of this monster like character which is a representation of his brother/dad/step dad that's very abusive. 
I think that's how the movie goes. Out between 1995-2005 but could be wrong. I have searched the internet to no avail, please help, its driving me mad. Thanks. 
